# loading error Acr UserDialogs

Tags: xamarin

I'm using this function plus this giving error when running on ios, android works correctly
[image]

```
  public async Task<ObservableCollection<ItemRss>> BaixarFeed()
    {
        using (Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Carregando..."))
        {
           //download
        }
    }
```

the error occurs in this command Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Carregando...")

If I remove the command, this works.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, figure out what is null. Then fix it.

Comment: I am not getting identified where this null value is

Comment: I did a test here, after the application is open, the function works, only when it opens the application that it gives that null